# SQL Generate every street number between two street number and keep zip code

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have a dataset that has an inferior and Superior street number with street name and zip code. I would like to generate a dataset that contains every number between each street number.

For example, I have this dataset:

```
Inferior_Street_Number  Superior_street_number Zip_code
100                     105                    G1W2X5
100                     105                    G1W2X7
202                     204                    G1W2X7
```

And would like to have this output:

```
Street number    Zip_code
100              G1W2X5
101              G1W2X5
102              G1W2X5
103              G1W2X5
104              G1W2X5
105              G1W2X5
100              G1W2X7
101              G1W2X7
102              G1W2X7
103              G1W2X7
104              G1W2X7
105              G1W2X7
202              G1W2X7
203              G1W2X7
204              G1W2X7
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks! 
Nick  (I'm sorry for my English)

Comment: I am using Proc SQL with SAS EG on an Oracle DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence number table, this problem decomposes into a fairly simple join operation. Here's a Transact-SQL example where most of it is making the sequence:

```
-- Sample sequence table, there are tons of ways to generate these
DECLARE @Sequence TABLE(
    Number INT PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT
    @Sequence( Number )
VALUES
    (0), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ), ( 8 ), ( 9 )

INSERT
    @Sequence( Number )
SELECT
    Ones.Number + 10 * Tens.Number + 100 * Hundreds.Number + 1000 * Thousands.Number
FROM
    @Sequence AS Ones
CROSS JOIN
    @Sequence AS Tens
CROSS JOIN
    @Sequence AS Hundreds
CROSS JOIN
    @Sequence AS Thousands

EXCEPT

SELECT Number FROM @Sequence


SELECT
    [Sequence].Number AS StreetNumber
,   ZipCodes.Zip_code
FROM
    @ZipCodes AS ZipCodes
JOIN    @Sequence AS [Sequence] ON (
        [Sequence].Number BETWEEN ZipCodes.Inferior_Street_Number AND ZipCodes.Superior_Street_Number
    )   
ORDER BY
    Zip_code, StreetNumber
```